# Jenkins parameters populate dropdown based on first dropdown selection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins pipeline parameters, auto populate the target environment based on the section of environment.

- If environment select the 'Test' and Target Environment should be populate 'Test-US' and 'Test-UK'
- If environment select the 'Dev' and Target Environment should be populate 'Dev-US' and 'Dev-UK'

  pipeline{
  parameters {
  choice(name: 'Environment' choices: ['Test', 'Dev'])
  choice(name: 'Target Environment' choices: ['Test-US', 'Test-UK', 'Dev-US', 'Dev-UK'])
  }
  stage('build') {
  steps{
  script {
  echo 'executing.'
  } } } }

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins Active Choice plugin for such purpose. See the link below. There are some detailed examples that could be quite similar to your case.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/